# "String cannot be converted to PubliclyCloneable" Java Issue

Tags: java

So I am trying to add a few strings to a Doubly Linked list but I keep getting the error that String cannot be converted to PubliclyCloneable (an interface that extends Cloneable, use for the purposes of creating a clone() and copy constructor, a la my textbook's explanation). Here is what my demo code looks like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    DoublyLinkedList list1 = new DoublyLinkedList();
    DoublyLinkedList.DoublyLinkedIterator i = list1.iterator();

    String pittsburgh1 = new String("Penguins");
    String pittsburgh2 = new String("Pirates");
    String pittsburgh3 = new String("Steelers");

    list1.addToStart(pittsburgh1);
    list1.addToStart(pittsburgh2);
    list1.addToStart(pittsburgh3);

    System.out.println("List contains:");
    i.restart();
    while (i.hasNext())
        System.out.println(i.next());
    System.out.println("");
```

Here is the beginning part of the class DoublyLinkedList:

```
public class DoublyLinkedList<T extends PubliclyCloneable> implements PubliclyCloneable
{
private class TwoWayNode<T>
{
    private T data;
    private TwoWayNode<T> next;
    private TwoWayNode<T> prev;

    public TwoWayNode()
    {
        data = null;
        next = null;
        prev = null;
    }

    public TwoWayNode(T newData, TwoWayNode<T> prevNode, TwoWayNode<T> nextNode)
    {
        data = newData;
        next = nextNode;
        prev = prevNode;
    }
}
```

Here is the method that is causing the compiler error:

```
public void addToStart(T itemData)
{
    TwoWayNode<T> newHead = new TwoWayNode(itemData, null, head);
    if (head != null)
    {
        head.prev = newHead;
    }
    head = newHead;
}
```

And here is the interface that I am using:

```
public interface PubliclyCloneable extends Cloneable
{
public Object clone();
}
```

So there is probably something that I am overlooking here, but is what I am trying to accomplish even possible? Is there some sort of typecast or type assignment I can do to add those three strings to my List?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `addToStart` method accepts an argument of type `T`, where `T` is defined by the class as `T extends PubliclyCloneable`.

Since `java.lang.String` does not implement `PubliclyCloneable`, it cannot be an argument type for your `DoublyLinkedList`. If you want a `main` function to test your class, I'd implement a simple-stupid `PubliclyClonableString` class::

```
public class PubliclyClonableString implements PubliclyClonable {
    private String s;
    public PubliclyClonableString (String s) {
        this.s = s;
    }

    @Override
    public String clone() {
        return s; // OK, since Strings are immutable
    }

    // getter, setter, etc.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to add Strings to a list that you have declared will hold PubliclyCloneable. Either put PubliclyCloneable objects in it or declare that it will hold Strings.

Answer (score 0):

Since `DoublyLinkedList` requires a class which extends `PubliclyCloneable`, you'll have to make your custom string class:

```
public class CloneableString implements PubliclyCloneable {

    private String str;

    public CloneableString(String str) {
        this.str = str;
    }

    public String getString() {
        return str;
    }

    @Override
    public Object clone();
        return new CloneableString(str);
    }

}
```